# how to access the binary file in GCP cloud function [PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

```
def process_audio(request):

 return theTextFile
```

I've set up a GCP HTTP function in python, when i make a request to it I'll send an audio(wav) file to it for processing, My question is

1. How can I access the binary file audio.wav from the request? (request will be around 1 mb)
2. How can I return a binary file for example a text file in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request` object is a [Werkzeug request object](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request). To get an uploaded file from it, you can call:

```py
request.files.get('your_form_input_name')
```

Which will give you a [`werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) object.

For sending a file as a response, you can use [`flask.send_file()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file):

```py
import flask
...
return flask.send_file('your_filename')
```